# MultiSelect Array (Javascript to MySql)

Tags: javascript, mysql, select

I have done a multiselect:
This is Client side

```
<select name="country" data-placeholder="Choose a Country..."  tabindex="2">

            <option name="country"  value="United States">United States</option>
            <option  name="country" value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
</select>
```

And this is the server

```
String[] totcountry = request.getParameterValues("country");

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db",
            "root", "admin");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();

    int var = st.executeUpdate("insert into table(totcountry) values ('" + totcountry + "')");
```

But in the Database instead of United States, United Kingdom, it return something like [Ljava.lang.String;@7780d0fe

Obviously if I write   `String totcountry = request.getParameterValues("country")[0]+","+request.getParameterValues("country")[1];` it works, but you must chose both the country... Where I am wrong? 
Thanks!!

Comment: Try `String totcountry = request.getParameter("country");` instead. `getParameterValues()` is usually used when multiple values are selected (like in the case of checkboxes, or a listbox).

Comment: If I write so it return just the first choice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `String.join(",", totcountry)` in your query. totcountry is an array, therefore converting it to a String yields such a reference id like you got.